# Api Gateway not see other services in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, deployment, microservices

I have a problem with containerization of my small microservice project with using `docker-compose`. After build and up belowed compose I see that everythin is working and all services is running, but right now I have a one issue. My `api-gateway` service is not connecting to the other services and when api-gateway is trying to make request to eq. `account-service` then console throw me this:

```
api-gateway  | [Nest] 1  - 05/21/2022, 9:38:51 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3002
```

So, I think that the problem is in connection in my container, between all of the services in him.

Can someon tell me what have i'm doing wrong?

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
    
services:
  api:
    container_name: api-gateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/api/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    hostname: api
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - backend
  account:
    container_name: account-service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/account/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    hostname: account
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    networks:
      - backend
  workspace:
    container_name: workspace-service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/workspace/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    hostname: workspace
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    networks:
      - backend
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.8.0-alpine as develop

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . .

RUN npm run build workspace

CMD node dist/apps/workspace/main
```

Dockerfile is this same for all of the services.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In docker compose the services are available to each other under hostnames corresponding to their container names (in this case `api-service`, `account-service`, `workspace-service`) or their names (`api`, `account`, `workspace`) if the container names are not set.

Consequently, in order to make requests within the services, you need to send requests to

```
"http://workspace-service:3002"
```

instead of

```
"http://localhost:3002"
```

Comment: would this work also if i removed hostname from docker-compose?

Comment: Yes, `hostname:` doesn't do anything observable in most cases (with a specific exception for RabbitMQ).  You can also safely delete `container_name:`, and if you delete all of the `networks:` blocks, Compose will automatically create a network named `default` for you.  All of this is detailed in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.